# Выборка нескольких элементов по одному полю sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица "m", в ней 3ри поля: `id,name,value`

Сейчас в ней около тысячи записей.

Вопрос такой: Как мне сделать выборку по полю `name`, где допустим `name` равен `foo` и `bar`. Т.е. мне нужно получить две записи из таблицы с `name=foo` и `name=bar`.
Сейчас это работает путем нескольких запросов прокрученых через цикл, но хотелось бы засунуть все в один запрос.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы предоставили ваш код, чтобы можно было дать более качественный ответ.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы привести пример исходных данных и результата на этих данных с пояснением, почему именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под выборку должны попадать строки, поле `name` в которых может иметь одно из этих значений (`'foo'` или `'bar'`), то запрос может быть такой:

```
SELECT * FROM m WHERE `name` IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно то это должно помочь:

```
SELECT * FROM m WHERE `name`='foo' OR `name`='bar'
```